# Configuration value from KeyVault is null only in `StorageCredential` constructor

Tags: azure, configuration, publish, azure-keyvault, .net-5

I've been successfully loading configuration values from Azure KeyVault in production for a while. Today I added a new secret to KeyVault as well as a new service for that key (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth):

```
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("myAccount", configuration["BlobStorage:Key"]);
```

Only during the the publish process to production do I get an argument null exception

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'keyValue')

`keyValue` is the parameter name for the second arguement of the `StorageCredentials` constructor. When I run this locally in production mode, I can see the string value being successfully fetched from the KeyVault. If I copy the string out of the KeyVault and paste it in the argument as a literal, it publishes just fine. If I replace that parameter with a known, working KeyVault secret like `configuration["ConnectionString:database"]`, that **also comes in as null**, even though it is loaded in when used elsewhere in code.

If I try something a little more literal like:

```
var stableKey = configuration["KeyIveUsedBeforeThatWorks"]
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("myAccount", stableKey);
```

I will still get an error on publish that parameter 'keyValue' is null. Here is how KeyVault values are being loaded:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultUri"));
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

Why are all KeyVault values loaded as `null` during publish for *just* this `StorageCredentials` constructor?

Comment: Could  you please tell me how you load configuration values from Azure KeyVault?

Comment: @JimXu Updated. Please note, all my other keyvault values are loaded fine. I can even load this new value into a variable, but if I use this variable inside the StorageCredential constructor, thats when it claims it is null.